# create array timelist from 00:00 - 23:55 for every 5 minutes

Tags: php, datetime, time

I want to create an array with all the 5 minute times from 00:00 to 23:55

On this forum I found:

```
$minutes = 5;
$endtime = new DateTime('2012-01-01 09:00');

//modified the start value to get something _before_ the endtime:
$time = new DateTime('2012-01-01 00:00');
$interval = new DateInterval('PT' . $minutes . 'M');

while($time < $endtime){
    $time->add($interval);
echo $time->format('Y-m-d H:i');
}
```

How do I change this so that the output can be used with json?

For example:-

```
$aArray = {"00:00":"00:00","00:05":"00:05", ......"23:55":"23:55"}
```

My problem is not in creating json, but in creating an hour/minute list without the date part.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are allmost there, just little tweek and as Terje suggest using H:i. Perhaps something like this:

```
$startTime  = new \DateTime('2010-01-01 00:00');
$endTime    = new \DateTime('2010-01-01 23:55');
$timeStep   = 5;
$timeArray  = array();

while($startTime <= $endTime)
{
    $timeArray[] = $startTime->format('H:i');
    $startTime->add(new \DateInterval('PT'.$timeStep.'M'));
}

echo json_encode($timeArray);
```

Answer (score 4):

The argument to `DateTime::format` controlls the selection of fields like this:

- Y: year
- m: month
- d: day
- H: hour
- i: minute

To get only hour and minute: Use `'H:i'` as format string.

For more formatting options: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

And if you can't use the DateTime functions, I would have generated the array like this:

```
$times = array();
for ($h = 0; $h < 24; $h++){
  for ($m = 0; $m < 60 ; $m += 5){
    $time = sprintf('%02d:%02d', $h, $m);
    $times["'$time'"] = "'$time'";
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
echo json_encode($Var);
```

This should  do the trick.. View the manual here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: i edited my problem, because creating json itself wasnt my problem. sorry if i was not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's way late but below method may be helpful to someone

```
$step = 5;
$periods = new DatePeriod(
    new DateTime("2021-01-01 00:00:00"),
    new DateInterval('PT' . $step . 'M'),
    new DateTime("2021-01-01 23:59:00")
);

foreach($periods as $d){
    echo $d->format("H:i");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Have to update my php version first to use these DateTime class :(
So for now i just wrote it out and used 15 minutes interval like:

```
function json_select_starttijd_ronde()
{
$jsonStarttijd_ronde = array();

$jsonStarttijd_ronde['00:00'] = '00:00';
$jsonStarttijd_ronde['00:15'] = '00:15';
    // etcetera

$jsonStarttijd_ronde['23:45'] = '23:45';

return $jsonStarttijd_ronde;

}
```

Comment: Then I would have used a pair of nested loops to generate the array content.  See my updated answer.